# "Invalid Service Definition" when using DI->Get Phalcon PHP

Tags: php, phalcon

This question is related to [Appending multiple config arrays in PhalconPHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500816/appending-multiple-config-arrays-in-phalconphp/13503831#comment18604749_13503831)

I am trying to get retrieve an object from the DI using the get method.

The object is being set like this

```
// $new_array the array with the merged data. Load it in a 
// \Phalcon\Config object
$config = new \Phalcon\Config($new_array);

//Store the config in your DI container for easier use
$di->set('config', $config);
```

And this is the error message I am getting when I call

```
$new_array = $di->get('config');
```

> [Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\DI\Exception' with message 'Invalid
>   service definition. Missing 'className' parameter']

I have been stuck on this for a few days now so would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead in the set:

```
$di->set('config', function() {
   ...
   return new \Phalcon\Config($new_array);
});
```

Comment: use [setShared] to avoid recreating the Config every time you call the get

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing `$di->set('config', $new_array);` instead of `$di->set('config', $config);` :)

Answer (score 0):

If your $config variable is an array. You can refer my answer at [Missing 'className' parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202801/missing-classname-parameter)

Here is the repost:
I found that Phalcon DI container use array for Constructor Injection. So if you set an array into Phalcon DI container, it understands that you want to set an object by using Constructor Injection and it requires "className" definition. You can check this at Constructor Injection section at https://docs.phalconphp.com/3.4/en/di.

Example of constructor injection in the document:

```
$di->set(
    'response',
    [
        'className' => 'Phalcon\Http\Response'
    ]
);

$di->set(
    'someComponent',
    [
        'className' => 'SomeApp\SomeComponent',
        'arguments' => [
            [
                'type' => 'service',
                'name' => 'response',
            ],
            [
                'type'  => 'parameter',
                'value' => true,
            ],
        ]
    ]
);
```

MY SOLUTION:

1. Suppose that I want to set this config array ['key' => 'value'] into DI.
2. I create MyConfigFactory class, which has function build to return ['key' => 'value'].
3. I inject my config as below:

   ```
   $di->set('myConfigFactory', new MyConfigFactory());
   $di->set('config', function () use ($di) {
       return $di->get('myConfigFactory')->build();
   });
   ```