# Missing 'className' parameter

Tags: phalcon

I am working on a old project change request and the project was developed in phalcon 1.2.6 verson. When I am trying to execute the application the application returns an error. After doing some R&D I found that the system did not find the config key from the `$di` object.

When I am trying to print the `$di` object it's printing properly with key config. But when trying to access the config key, I am unable to access it.

When the system tries to execute the below code, it throws an exception.

```
$di = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault();
print_r($di['config']);
```

I am getting the below error.

```
Invalid service definition. Missing 'className' parameter
#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\DI\Service\Builder->build(Object(Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault), Array, NULL)
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\DI\Service->resolve(NULL, Object(Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault))
#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\DI->get('config', NULL)
#3 /var/www/sites/mfs_merged/apps/api/Module.php(44): Phalcon\DI->offsetGet('config')
#4 [internal function]: AppServer\Api\Module->registerServices(Object(Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault))
#5 /var/www/sites/mfs_merged/public/index.php(64): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#6 {main}
```

below is a part of my `$di` object

```
Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault Object
(
    [_services:protected] => Array
        (
            [...] => Phalcon\DI\Service Object
                (....)

            [config] => Phalcon\DI\Service Object
                (
                    [_name:protected] => config
                    [_definition:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [database] => Array
                                (
                                    [adapter] => Oracle
                                    [host] => 172.20.3.228
                                    [username] => XXXXX
                                    [password] => XXXXXXX
                                    [schema] => XE
                                    [dbname] => (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.20.3.228)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
                                )

                            [memcache] => Array
                                (
                                    [lifetime] => 3600
                                    [host] => localhost
                                    [port] => 11211
                                    [persistent] => 
                                )

                            [soapClient] => Array
                                (
                                    [connectionTimeout] => 60
                                    [exceptions] => 
                                    [trace] => 1
                                    [cache] => 0
                                    [useSoapHeader] => 1
                                    [soapHeader] => Array
                                        (
                                            [username] => XXXXX
                                            [password] => XXXXXX
                                        )
                                )
                            [SMSCodesLogPath] => /var/www/sites/mfs_merged/config/TZ/../../public/files/_SMSTokens/tokens_TZ.log
                        )

                    [_shared:protected] => 1
                    [_sharedInstance:protected] => 
                )
        )

    [_sharedInstances:protected] => Array
        (.....)

    [_freshInstance:protected] => 1
)
```

Comment: Can you show us your code where you set your config into your DI?

Comment: Maybe also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/20737854/4497805

Comment: I am already checked the above link. its not working

Comment: If you can't solve your issue, I'd recommend updating to the [latest release of Phalcon v1](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tree/1.3.6). There were a bunch of bug fixes in the versions after 1.2.6. (Including some bug fix for accessing DI objects).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with you. and I found that Phalcon DI container use array for Constructor Injection. So if you set an array into Phalcon DI container, it understands that you want to set an object by using Constructor Injection and it requires "className" definition. You can check this at Constructor Injection section at https://docs.phalconphp.com/3.4/en/di.

Example of constructor injection in the document:

```
$di->set(
    'response',
    [
        'className' => 'Phalcon\Http\Response'
    ]
);

$di->set(
    'someComponent',
    [
        'className' => 'SomeApp\SomeComponent',
        'arguments' => [
            [
                'type' => 'service',
                'name' => 'response',
            ],
            [
                'type'  => 'parameter',
                'value' => true,
            ],
        ]
    ]
);
```

MY SOLUTION:

1. Suppose that I want to set this config array ['key' => 'value'] into DI.
2. I create MyConfigFactory class, which has function build to return ['key' => 'value'].
3. I inject my config as below:

   ```
   $di->set('myConfigFactory', new MyConfigFactory());
   $di->set('config', function () use ($di) {
       return $di->get('myConfigFactory')->build();
   });
   ```

Good luck.